# Does knowing one encrypted character open up a security flaw?

Tags: php, security, encryption, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

One of the columns in a table in my API's database is an encrypted text formed of two pieces of information concatenated with a given delimiter, lets say a colon. The second piece of information is always, say, 12 characters long.

Does knowing this information open up a security flaw and potentially allow attackers to decrypt the information should they get a hold of it?

The information is encrypted using the php method `openssl_encrypt()` and with the 'aes-128-gcm' cipher.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [crypto.se] would be a more appropriate place to ask.

Comment: The security relies on how good the key is. If it is a random byte sequence it is secure. If it is a password it is not secure because it can be brute forced with a frequent password list. If it is a password use a key derivation function such as PBKDF2 or Argon2 to create a key from it. Finally, for a brute force attack to work the attacker must know when they are successful, in this case with GCM mode the authentication will succeed—but a brute force against a 128-bit will not be successful in time left in the universe.

Comment: @zaph My key is 60 chars long and was generated on random.org - A site which claims to be truly random. It also has a few additional non-random (but still pseudo-random) words typed into the middle of it. It is the same key I use for hashing my passwords - is that poor practice?

Comment: @Barmar - I didn't know that forum existed - but even still, is it not acceptable here as it is loosely centred on PHP?

Comment: @TobySmith 1. An `aes-128-gcm` key is 128-bits (16-bytes). 2. No that is not secure for passwords. For php there is a simple and secure pair of methods: `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`. See passwsord [hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) & [verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). The salt must be a different random sequence for each password and there needs to be a minimum of CPU time consumed of around 100ms, this pair of functions takes care of all that by default.

Comment: @zaph - sorry, my bad: I do use those two methods, but the key is something I use elsewhere (just not for hashing passwords). So you're saying the key I use for `aes-128-gcm` needs to be 16-bytes long?

Comment: Yep, that is what the 128 means in `aes-128-gcm`, the key length in bits. More than likely the extra bytes are just ignored. AES supports 128, 192 & 256 bit keys. A 128-bit is completely secure against brute force attacks, 256 is popular because everyone likes bigger numbers and it will be secure against quantum computers if and when.

Comment: @TobySmith "as it is loosely centred on PHP?" Wouldn't the question be the same if you were using Python, C, Javascript, or any other language? It's just a question about the security of the encryption scheme, the language is irrelevant. And the people who know most about cryptography and code breaking hang out on that other forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking about is known in the literature as a **partially known-plaintext attack** (partial-KPA).

> The information is encrypted using the php method openssl_encrypt() and with the 'aes-128-gcm' cipher.

AES-GCM combines AES-CTR with GHASH (a polynomial MAC over GF(2^128)).

Answering your question further requires delving a bit deeper into the cryptography weeds, but generally:

- AES is considered a secure block cipher.
- CTR mode turns a block cipher into a stream cipher.
- Stream cipher encryption is conceptually equivalent to One-Time Pads, except the keystream is generated from the key and nonce, and thus can only have a finite (in this case, 128-bit) security level.

> One of the columns in a table in my API's database is an encrypted text formed of two pieces of information concatenated with a given delimiter, lets say a colon. The second piece of information is always, say, 12 characters long.

The only thing you can infer from an AES-GCM ciphertext is the length of the plaintext.

In order to be able infer the remainder of the keystream from one byte of ciphertext (and a corresponding known plaintext for that byte), AES would need to be a *very* insecure block cipher. Since we know (thanks to roughly 21 years of cryptanalysis effort) that AES *is* a secure block cipher, and AES-GCM is a secure authenticated cipher mode, partial-KPAs are not a concern for this construction.